# Radiaton of black body

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We have : $E=h/f$

I realised that the problem what quanta solved was that $h/0$ equals infinity but energy can't be infinity. But when frequency is zero we haven't any energy to calculate - there is no real solution. But Planck came with another solution: The light is packages with different energy - so we always have integer energy score. Why solved he solved problem? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you edit your question please? "why solved he solved problem" doesn't exactly make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You have catastrophically miscopied the formula you quote. The [correct relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{E=h\times f.}
$$
If the frequency is zero, the energy is also zero. There is no problem to begin with.

It is possible you were thinking of $E=h/\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength. In this case, a frequency of zero corresponds to infinite wavelength, so $E=0$ and a wavelength of zero corresponds to infinite frequency, so infinite energy as well.